# Need other than id as a primary key in rails active record migration script

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-migrations

I have a table  called students

```
mysql> desc students;
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| height             | decimal(15,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name               | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| text               | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status             | tinyint(4)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at         | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at         | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to create a new table called students_data which has student_name as foreign key and name as primary key from students table. How should I change my script? The following script takes id as primary key from students table

```
class CreateStudentsData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students_data do |t|
      t.belongs_to :students, :foreign_key => :student_name, :primary_key => :name
    end
  end
end
```

How should I change my script to get name as primary key?

NOTE: I don't want to set primary_key id as false as suggested [here](http://www.speakingcode.com/2013/12/07/gracefully-using-custom-primary-keys-in-rails-4-routes-controllers-models-associations-and-migrations/). I need id and name both as primary key.

Comment: just for interest: why do you need it? why not to use `student_id` in student_data table?

Comment: @IS04 - Its my manager requirement

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link

http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/